# Suggestions for Short Examples Contrasting Functional Programming Languages

Tags: functional-programming, lisp

A fellow student and I are writing a paper on functional programming for a programming languages course, part of which will be comparing and contrasting Lisp (Scheme), ML (SML), and Haskell. We'll be coding the same algorithm in each language and we're at a bit of a loss for exactly *what* to code. We would be grateful for some suggestions for algorithms that fit the bill (described below). We'll work out the code---we're just looking for suggestions. But if there's a particular tricky point or useful idiom we'd welcome a heads-up.

We envision the code being about a page. In particular, the professor wants something more substantial than a line or two. To the degree possible, we'd like to use this to contrast the styles of the three languages and at the same time showcase the benefits of functional programming. I considered quicksort, but the standard Haskell code is just a line or two.

I would have tagged this with "homework" and "soft question" (as well as "ML" and "Haskell"), but those tags don't seem to exist. Also, I wasn't sure whether Computer Science or Stack Overflow was the right place for this, but decided on Computer Science because we're not really looking for worked-out code or solutions to a particular coding problem. Instead we're looking to demonstrate the benefits of the functional programming paradigm and three important branches thereof.

Comment: What are the key differences in the languages?

Comment: @DaveClarke Well, we're still researching/reading and writing the paper so I can't quite regurgitate a list at the moment, but I'd say type systems (static vs dynamic, strong vs weak (modulo definition), type inference), strict/eager vs non-strict/lazy evaluation, availability of pattern matching and algebraic data types (ADT), and syntax in general. Lisp (Scheme): dynamic, weak(?), eager, parens and prefix syntax. ML (SML): static, strong, eager, inference, patterns and ADT, "mathematical" syntax. Haskell: static, strong, lazy, inference, patterns and ADT, "mathematical" syntax.

Comment: @DaveClarke Oh, and I left off a key point: Purity. While possibly not well-defined, Haskell would generally be considered a "pure" functional language while Lisp (Scheme) and ML (SML) would not because while they encourage functional programming style they allow manipulation of state. Again this depends on your definition of "pure" which seems not to be settled and is the subject of at least one paper.

Comment: community wiki?

Comment: @ThomasKlimpel, why?  (Community wiki is not a way to repair questions that are off-topic or too broad or that ask for a "big list of X" or that don't admit a single, objectively-selectable answer.)

Comment: @D.W. This question might be off-topic, but it isn't too broad. If it were too broad, then there should be a way to narrow it down. The "too broad" close reason contains the following text: "Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs." I have the impression that this clearly shows that the "too broad" close reason is not applicable for this question.

Comment: @ThomasKlimpel, ["If your question ... has many valid answers, it's probably too broad for our format."](http://cs.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions)  That seems to me to describe this question -- there are many possible valid answers, and the question does not provide any objective criteria to select a single correct answer.

Comment: I would suggest an interpreter for a small language of expressions with numerical and symbolic computation. May be a little more than a page, but can be kept small enough. It should be better than an isolated algorithm. I remember giving the writing of the symbolic part as an exam, and it worked rather well (the students were good, too). You want structural issues, not algorithmic complexity.

Comment: The point of my question was not so much for you to provide me with an answer, but to provide you with a starting point for highlighting the differences in the languages.

Comment: Thanks for you suggestions. Sorry if it didn't quite fit the format. @babou we ended up implementing an evaluator for abstract syntax trees (ASTs) for the toy language of our text, called "While". The text was Nielson and Nielson's Semantics. We did a While evaluator program for each of the 3 languages we covered. We did ASTs to avoid parsing text.

Answer (score 1):

- [Project Euler](https://projecteuler.net) has nice problems for showcasing the core of a programming language.
- An important part of a programming language are user defined (container) data structures. Bread and butter containers include random access arrays, bidirectional lists, hash tables, and search trees. You may take the implementations from standard libraries of the languages to get interesting real world programs for you comparisons.
- A strong point of functional programming languages is that they allow modular reuse of standard algorithms. The C++ stl header [algorithm](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/) provides a nice collection of those reusable standard algorithms.